# Range protection timing out in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

The below script is set as an installable trigger (onEdit) on my spreadsheet. However, it times-out when removing editors. There are roughly 12-15 editors that are removed when this script executes. **The execution transcript shows 30+ seconds to run this**:

```
    function onEdit() {

      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var ss = s.getActiveSheet();
      var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
      var lastColumn = activeRange.getLastColumn();

      // if the last col in the edited range is not 11, exit function
      if (lastColumn !== 11) {
        return;
      }

      var rangeHeight = activeRange.getHeight();
      var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
      var owners = ["email1@test.com", "email2@test.com", "email3@test.com"];
      var editors = s.getEditors();
      var ProtectionRng = ss.getRange(activeRow, 2, rangeHeight, 10);

      if (lastColumn === 11) {
        var Protection = ProtectionRng.protect();
        Protection.removeEditors(editors);
        if (Protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          Protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        Protection.addEditors(owners);
      }
   }
```

Is there any reason this would take so long to execute? Taken from above, is this the fastest way to handle range protections and add/remove editors?:

```
        var Protection = ProtectionRng.protect();
        Protection.removeEditors(editors);
        if (Protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          Protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        Protection.addEditors(owners);
```

Comment: If this is something that you're doing now, I know that Google has been having trouble today. Perhaps try again later?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I've been working on this one for several weeks now with similar results. I did notice the issue with Google today but I think it's just coincidence.